# htaccess how to change url to point a virtual host?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site (let's say **mainsite.com**) with a subdirectory (**mainsite.com/mysubdir**) with files (html, php). I have a Virtual Host (**mysubdir.mainsite.com**) which is the preferred way to access those files.

The question is: I want to avoid the **mainsite.com/mysubdir** access, modifying accordingly the **.htaccess** in the main directory. I've found several answers in the opposite way, say redirect the subdomain to a subdirectory, but nothing about my need.

I think it can be achieved with **RewriteCond / RewriteRule** commands, but I can't figure the right syntax. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What do you want to happen when user tries `mainsite.com/mysubdir/index.html` in his browser?

Comment: I don't want /mysubdir to be accesible directly. I could reject directly such a request in .htaccess, but maybe it should be more polite to reformat the URL setting the correct path to the virtual host.

Comment: Do you have access to apache configuration files, or `.htaccess` is the only option?

Comment: I have access to both of them. It's easier to do modifying httpd.conf?

Comment: [In general, you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/docroot/

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule /mysubdir/(.*) http://mysubdir.example.com/$1

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysubdir.example.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/docroot/mysubdir/
</VirtualHost>
```